Sind Umfragen, die keine Meinungen sondern regionale Sachverhalte abfragen, erlaubt?
In der Frage Regionalvarianten: Die Äpfel sind alle/aus? wird abgefragt, in welchen Regionen des deutschen Sprachraums welche Formulierungsvarianten einer bestimmten Aussage gängig sind. Das ist zwar keine Frage nach Meinungen, hat damit aber meiner Meinung nach große Ähnlichkeiten. Ich würde diese Frage gerne schließen, finde in unserem Regelwerk aber keinen Paragraphen, mit dem ich das begründen könnte.

Warum würdest die Frage gern schließen? Das zu wissen würde die Diskussion bereichern und die Entscheidung vereinfachen.

@JonathanHerrera: Weil die Frage eine Umfrage ist und Stackexchange nicht für Umfragen gemacht ist.

Eine schnelle Recherche über regional ergibt zahlreiche Fragen ähnlichen Typs, die sich durchaus auch hoher Wertungen erfreuen, beispielsweise:

Verwendung von »stromern«
Nuancen der regionalen und stilistischen Verteilung von "put-Verben" (vom OP)
is "keine blasse Ahnung haben" used somewhere
Nuancen der regionalen und stilistischen Verteilung von "put-Verben"

Ich sehe also keine direkte Veranlassung, hier aufgrund eines eher abstrakten Arguments neue Beschränkungen einzuführen, zumal eine einzige Antwort mit einer Verteilungskarte weitere Antworten überflüssig machen könnte.
